# permutation with duplicates ranking with DI Sequence

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, permutation, combinatorics

I want to rank and unrank through a subset of permutations given by length. The subset is definded as follows:

Example for permutation length 5 with the elements `1,1,2,2,3`

We have the Input the Bitstring `0101` length 4 (always permutation length - 1).

0 means 2 consecutive elements are Increasing or Equal.

1 means 2 consecutive elements are Decreasing.

For this Bitstring exist the subset with following permutations with the elements `1,1,2,2,3`:

`1,2,1,3,2` Rank 0

`1,3,2,2,1` Rank 1

`2,2,1,3,1` Rank 2

`2,3,1,2,1` Rank 3

The Bitstring defined subset of permutations I want to rank and unrank? Is there an algotrithmic way for a given permutation elements and the bitstring to do this without create every permutation and check?

Here is a solution for permutations without duplicates maybe this can be adapted:

[permutation ranking with DI sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551442/permutation-ranking-with-di-sequence#)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Simple recursion should do it. Pick any number as the first. The following numbers must obey the Bitstring.

Comment: @user3386109 It's not that simple: not any initial value will lead to a solution.

Comment: @Prune I'm aware of that. Without the Bitstring, the recursion would generate all possible permutations. The Bitstring limits the choices at each level of recursion, **after the first**, since the Bitstring only has `n-1` bits of information, and there are `n` numbers to choose.

Comment: I merely want to make sure that OP realizes that this is not an automatic, single-path solution.  It may involve dead-ends and backtracking.